Anime about a girl who can see spirits that nobody else can
I watched this 7-8 years ago. The anime was about this little girl who (I think she had brown hair?) becomes this "chosen one" who can see spirits that nobody else can. She's important for keeping the peace between the spirit world and the human world (I think?) I only remember specific episodes but it may have had two seasons. I remember the intro and outro for the show changed later, so I think it had two.
One episode I remember was about her being invited to a spirit world festival and I think she had some fun there. Another episode has her cleaning out her home and the spirits were hanging out with her (I think her home was a shrine or maybe she had to clean a shrine too?) She also had like 2 best friends who were her age. It was like a slice of life, no romance iirc kind of anime.
edit: It wasn't school-based, and I think she lived in a small town. After she became the "chosen one" she didn't really have to go to school anymore.
edit: It was Kamichu! I was beginning to think I imagined it. Thank you to those who commented, I really appreciate it!

Keeping the peace between humans and spirits sounds like In/Spectre but alas nothing else matches.

Can you remember any of the spirit characters? Either names or descriptions would help a lot. Was one a fox? It sounds a little like Gingitsune.

This sounds a lot like "Kamichu!" although there was a tiny bit of frustrated romance between the girl (who became a kami overnight) and a nerd calligrapher.  While she did mostly continue at school, she was called out frequently to deal with national- or international-level problems (like invading Martians) and did spend a semester in the spirit world.  There was definitely a trip to a spirit convention, where she attended a bunch of seminars and collected attendance stamps.
If the first few episodes featured a typhoon whose cloud pattern resembled this girl's face, it's definitely "Kamichu!"  If one of her two close friends is the daughter of an impoverished local shrine who tries to rope the girl into all sorts of money-making ventures, it's probably "Kamichu!"

Possibly "Re-Kan!" ?
To quote wikipedia

High school girl Hibiki Amami has a sixth sense of perceiving and interacting with ghosts and supernatural beings, as well as talking with cats and other animals, but none of her peers share that ability. After transferring to Hanazuka Prefectural High School, she becomes friends with some classmates who put up with her antics, including class representative Narumi Inoue, who despises anything related to the occult. The story follows their everyday antics.

There was anime adaptation in April and June 2015.
Look at episode list here and see if anything rings a bell:
Episode list.
